# Android - ImageButton not displaying

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imagebutton

I have layout with `NestedScrollView` and within `RecyclerView`, in the `Recyclerview` i have `Cardview` that holds `ImageButton`. 
For some reason the `ImageButton` are not displaying when i run the application.

**Layout Code**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.world.bolandian.talent.activities.SingleUserProfileActivity">


    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/singleCvUserProfile"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapWell
        android:id="@+id/singleBootstrapWell"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="174dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:bootstrapSize="xl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewDetails"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/singleAboutMe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />
    </com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapWell>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSingle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/singleBootstrapWell"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/singleBootstrapWell"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/singleBootstrapWell"
        tools:listitem="@layout/single_video_item" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The `RecyclerView` has listitem of `single_video_item`

**Layout Code - singleVideoItem**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/singleIvThumbnailVideo">


                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutLikesSingle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout2">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibLikeSingle"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/bootstrap_thumbnail_background"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_like_grey" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibCommentSingle"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/bootstrap_thumbnail_background"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_comment" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibShareSingle"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/bootstrap_thumbnail_background"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_share" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/commentsSingleItem"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

For some reason the `ImageButton` are not displaying, but can be touch.

When i click on the button area there is a ripple effect, the buttons can be clicked but they are not shown.

**Here an print screen of the NestedScrollView with the RecyclerView**
The `ImageButtons` are not been display

[image: Not displaying the imagebuttons]

**Here another `RecyclerView` but not in `NestedScrollView` and here the `ImageButtons` been display**

[image: Displaying the imagebuttons]

Any idea why in the `NestedScrollView` the `ImageButtons` are not beening display?

Answer (score 0):

Try with background colour from white to some other colour. If not works try with only background instead of background tint. It will work. Background tint only works on API level 21+.